# Powershell and getcontent CR LF

Tags: powershell

Have a very simple powershell script to count the number of trades in a file:

```
(gc \\mimkeimc11n\Batch\FundQuest\TradeFiles\trades.dat |? {$_ -match 'SL|BY'} | Measure-Object | select count).count > \\mimkeimc11n\Batch\FundQuest\ConfirmtoFQ\NumberofTrades.txt
```

The problem I am running into is the output NumberofTrades.txt is including the number that I want, but also a CR LF, not sure why???  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
http://screencast.com/t/MGM3ZTc0Mzct

Comment: Quick answer: look at the behavior of Out-File. Your pipeline looks like it's doing it's job of piping exactly one integer to Out-File, so the problem is probably that Out-File puts a CRLF at the end of the line...or it somehow sees two elements in the pipeline(?).

Clarification: Out-File is the cmdlet that is run when you use the > operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell is pretty persistent about outputting newlines for you when you send strings to Out-File (alias >) or even Add/Set-Content.  It can be infuriating sometimes and makes me wish for a -NoNewLine parameter on these cmdlets.  For now you can use a .NET API e.g.:

```
$path = '\mimkeimc11n\Batch\FundQuest\ConfirmtoFQ\NumberofTrades.txt'
(gc \mimkeimc11n\Batch\FundQuest\TradeFiles\trades.dat | 
    ?{$_ -match 'SL|BY'} | Measure-Object).count |
 %{[IO.File]::WriteAllText($path, $_)}
```

Comment: thanks Keith this did the trick, and i couldn't agree more about the -nonewline, @ least give us some option

Comment: If anybody agrees with this need then vote on the suggestion at https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=524739